# String concatenation in Lua

Tags: lua

just reading up on Lua for a project. I do not like the '..' operator used to concatenate strings (just looks unnatural to me). I do not know enough about Lua yet - but it seems its very flexible.

Is it possible to somehow 'modify' this behaviour (perhaps using metatables?) so that I can use '+' instead of '..' for string concatenation?

Comment: @mudassir: I'm trying to make life easier for the script writers (and ultimately myself). The target audience are not coders. So I want them to be able to write simplistic statments like greeting = 'hello ' + 'world'

Comment: String concatenation with "+" is evil and anybody who implements it deserves to die a slow, painful death.

Comment: @skyeagle: `..` is too complicated for your users? I'd take that as a insult.

Comment: I think you will be better served using the default behavior.  If your audience is complete technophobes they likely wont have the prejudice towards a + operator which comes from using languages like c#, javascript, etc.

Comment: Let me add my voice to the chorus. I'd gently recommend giving your users a chance with the language as it stands before leaping out to change it. Otherwise, you are engaging in a kind of premature optimization. The choice of `..` for the operator was not completely arbitrary, it has worked quite well for a large community of users both programmers and non-programmers.

Comment: It's a bad idea to foist a non-standard version of a language on your users. Gary's Mod does the same thing, under the same guise (helping people). This is not an especially egregious case, but such modifications can only reduce the value of Lua books and online documentation for your users, while simultaneously reducing the value of their experience with the language ("I know Lua, see?" "Wait, what the hell is *that*? That's not Lua!")

Answer (score 6):

Try this code:

```
getmetatable("").__add = function(x,y) return x..y end
print("hello"+" "+"world")
```

Comment: I was just writing the same answer, you're quicker :)

Comment: Oh, ....it requires the **string library**!!! see http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#5.4

Comment: @ulrichb, yes it does require the string library. Sorry for not being clear.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it's possible.  [This article from IBM](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/linux/library/l-lua.html) has one example that uses a special "String" class:

> ```
> -- Overload the add operation
> -- to do string concatenation
> --
> mt = {}
>
> function String(string)
>   return setmetatable({value = string or ''}, mt)
> end
>
> -- The first operand is a String table
> -- The second operand is a string
> -- .. is the Lua concatenate operator
> --
> function mt.__add(a, b)
>   return String(a.value..b)
> end
>
> s = String('Hello')
> print((s + ' There ' + ' World!').value )
> ```

This approach has the advantage that it doesn't step on the toes of the existing string table, and it's slightly more clear to existing Lua users that you're doing something "different" with the `__add` operator.

Comment: Thanks for the prompt response. My target audience are complete technophobes. This likeley to confuse them (the script writers), even more than using the simple '..' to concatenate. Ah well ...